# How to set up tooltip text box position one time for every element?

Tags: html, css

Here is a simple calendar, and I have a tooltip textbox on days, on hovering it shows a description. But I made position css for every tooltip:

```
.newyear .tooltiptext { top:70px;
left:61px; width: 180px;}
.sixjanuar .tooltiptext { top:70px;
left:200px; width: 180px;}
.eightfebruar .tooltiptext { top:90px;
left:145px; width: 200px;}
.tenfebruar:hover .tooltiptext {
    top:95px; width: 200px; left: 195px;
}
.eleventfebruar:hover .tooltiptext {
    top:95px; width: 200px; left: 225px;
}

.twelvefebruar:hover .tooltiptext {
    top:122px; width: 200px; left: 60px;
}
```

Here is a demo: http://buhehe.de/kalender-2018/

Is any trick that I can use for make tooltip position one time, for every element?

Comment: position:relative on `td` and remove all this

Comment: thanks it works, but please see 1 april. It show on right side and half of tooltip is hidden.

Comment: And can u tell me please , why Juni is not on May's line? Why does it start in new line? i need 4 div element in each line.

Comment: in your CSS you have only this `.Januar, .Februar, .Maerz, .April` as a selector, so you need to also include the other months

Comment: for the hidden tooltip go to this `#heatmapthemead-the-content-container` you will see `overflow:hidden` replace hidden by visible

Comment: Overflow changed on #heatmapthemead-the-content-container but it doesn't show entire box on 1. april

Comment: i see there is hidden in other container too, so you need to change them all. You should have them visible in all the parent container to see the tooltip